# Working with tables within tables in python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx, data-extraction

I am using python-docx to modify particular table data in a word file. I have a word file with multiple tables and tables within tables. This is the [particular doc image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG9fe.png) with multiple tables and the numbered data needed.

problems:

Can I modify the numbered cells in a table inside a table in word file using python-docx

Can I achieve my requirement using python-docx

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, I've tried some table interation based on this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178914/how-to-retrieve-particular-table-data-in-multiple-tables-using-python-docx), but it only works by retrieving cell values. As this is actually a form, I have to modify certain values based on arguments provided by a Tkinter form.